# What is Point4D used for in WPF 3D?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, 3d

What is the normal use case for Point4D vs Point3D?

Is it for handling special geometry or just carrying a scalar field value around with the point or something more specialized?

Answer (score 2):

In order to represent a 3D [affine transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) where there might be a translation in addition to scaling and rotation as a matrix transform, you need to extend to 4D points and a 4x4 augmented matrix. (Consider that a 3x3 matrix could not translate the point (0, 0, 0) to a different location.)

In WPF the [Matrix3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.matrix3d.aspx) structure represents a 4x4 matrix, and [Point4D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point4D%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the augmented vector structure that you can multiply by a Matrix3D matrix. The extended vectors are sometimes called '[homogeneous 3D coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates)'.

Comment: So what is the difference between Matrix3D.Transform(Point3D) and Matrix3D.Transform(Point4D) does the Point3D version just drop the translation part of the affine transformation or does it internal promote to Point4D and then back to Point3D?

Comment: You get the same result as extending to a Point4D, though it is implemented directly with component-wise multiplication.

Comment: Note that promoting Point3D to Point4D sets the 4th component to 1 not to 0 otherwise the translation will be lost.